# Embed a Google Map into a dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to dynamically generate a Google map when the user submits a form, but the map does not appear in its div when the form is submitted.

I tested to see if the map populates on merely on pageload and it does, but when trying to use a div that displays onclick the map does not show.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" action="">
  <input type="text" id="addLocation"/>
  <button onclick="findLocation()" id="btnLocation">Find Location</button>
</form>

<div id="mapContainer"></div>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
function findLocation(){
  var inputString = $('#addLocation').val();
  $('#mapContainer').html('<div id="mapCanvas"></div>');

  var apiRequest = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxxxx.net/json/'+ inputString,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
  });

  apiRequest.done(function(data){
    var lat = data['latitude'];
    var lng = data['longitude'];

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 8
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), mapOptions);
    }

    // from GMaps API docs 
    function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' + '&callback=initialize';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    window.onload = loadScript;

   }); // ends .done statement 
 } // ends findLocation
```

It should be that when you click the Find Location button it will generate a map in the mapCanvas div but it does not.

I found out [from the Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch) that if you want to asynchronously load a map you have to use that loadScript function.

And yes, the map divs have widths and heights in the CSS, so that's not the problem. I think the problem is with the Javascript scopes. I'm doing something wrong with the order or placement of the calls, just not sure what.

Comment: You might be right about scope.The callback will prob be in window-scope and it won't be able to find your function. Try setting `window.initialize = initialize` and see if that calls the map OK.

Comment: Was a good idea, but I'm afraid calling initialize didn't do it.

Comment: Also you're missing `center:` in your mapOptions...

Comment: Oops, that was a typo, I actually had that in my local code. I've updated the question to show the center: option. Unfortunately that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Righto, I'm fairly sure you can simplify this a lot - try this - http://jsfiddle.net/cm476qy8/1/ (have simplified it a bit to account for lack of JSON)

Comment: I appreciate the fiddle, sirfriday. That helped wrapping my head around the problem. Much obliged!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is not true that you have to load the Maps API asynchronously when you want to create a map dynamically. You can load the API either using the asynchronous method or with a conventional `<script>` tag. Loading the API does not create a map; it merely loads the code. A map is not created until you call `new google.maps.Map()`.

So one easy solution would be to go back to a `<script>` tag to load the API, and simply call your `initialize()` function directly inside your ajax callback. (Or pull the code out of the `initialize()` function and just run it inline inside the callback.)

In fact, in your current code you are *already* loading the Maps API at page load time, with this line:

```
window.onload = loadScript;
```

That causes the `loadScript()` function to be called at page load time.

So you may as well just use a `<script>` tag to load the API, it's more or less the same thing you're doing now but simpler.

If you do want to load the Maps API dynamically, @sirfriday's comment is correct: your `initialize` function is not visible in the global scope, and it needs to be so the asynchronous API load can call it when ready.

You mentioned that "calling initialize didn't do it." - but you shouldn't be *calling* `initialize()` in this case, you should set `window.initialize` to be a reference to the function, e.g.:

```
window.initialize = initialize;  // note no () so it doesn't call it here
```

Or change the function like this:

```
window.initialize = function() {
    ...
};
```

And also if you want to load the API dynamically, don't do it at `onload` time. Instead, call your `loadScript()` function *inside* your ajax callback. That will give you the right sequence of operations:

1. Page loads
2. User interacts with it and the ajax request starts
3. Ajax request completes
4. Maps API loads
5. Your `initialize()` function gets called

Comment: yep - I reckon you're right that the async script load is making this needlessly complex - super-simple demo here without it. http://jsfiddle.net/cm476qy8/1/ Thanks for explaining what I was getting at with window.initialize!

Comment: Evidently the initialize function was the problem. Michael, you suggested: `(Or pull the code out of the initialize() function and just run it inline inside the callback.)` which did the trick. That and simplifying the API load script. Thank you!